# How to use hidden modules in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to import ByteArray ,from the Cryptonite library.
My cabal file has cryptonite in the Build depends ,and my import statement looks like this

```
import Crypto.Internal.ByteArray (ByteArray, Bytes)
import qualified Crypto.Internal.ByteArray as B
```

The error I get is 
Could not load module ‘Crypto.Internal.ByteArray’
    it is a hidden module in the package ‘cryptonite-0.25’
I have seen other code examples which use this specific import statement ,what am I missing here?

Comment: Where have you seen these other code examples?

Comment: I am actually trying to use some code from this library http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.25/docs/src/Crypto-PubKey-RSA-PKCS15.html#HashAlgorithmASN1

Comment: Right. So packages are allowed to use their own hidden internal modules, but nobody else is. Sorry. Find another way.

Answer (score 2):

As per [GHC Docs](https://ghc.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.2/packages.html), hidden modules

> "cannot be imported, but they are still subject to the overlapping
>   constraint: no other package in the same program may provide a module
>   of the same name."

Comment: I will say, I sometimes question the principle, or at least what some authors decide to stick in there. More than once I've had to copy and paste some internal module code, which is really not ideal due to possible version changes in the dependency not lining up well with the pasted code (though types would catch most issues).